# ftp_put to upload files to a server problems

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that is intended to allow file uploads to a server. I am programming an FTP client which is going well so far except that the files will not upload to the server. My form is as follows:

```
<form action='upload.php' id='upload'>
    <input type='file' name='file' />
    <input name='file_name' placeholder='File Name' />
    <input type='submit' value='upload' />
</form>
```

And here is my php:

```
<?php
    $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($_COOKIE['domain']);
    if(@ftp_login($ftp_connection, $_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password'])) {
        ftp_put($ftp_connection, $_REQUEST['file_name'], $_REQUEST['file']);
    }
    ftp_close($ftp_connection);
?>
```

Also note that all of those cookies work perfectly fine, as I use them to login to the FTP GUI.

Comment: If you are debugging, do not use `@` to suppress error / warnings! Cookie storing plain text password, you sure?

Comment: Login works 100% sure because as I said you have to log in in order to get to the GUI that brings you to the file uploader. I can access directories and such stuff but uploading will not work.

Comment: Is a full file pathway needed? If so how can I obtain the full file path because the input type='file' does not supply a full file path.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which is required when uploading files.

Plus a POST method is also required.

Modify your `<form...` to read as:

```
<form action='upload.php' id='upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
```

`<form>` defaults to GET when omitted.

Also have a look at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Example from that page:

```
<?php
$ftp_server="";
$ftp_user_name="";
$ftp_user_pass="";
$file = "";//tobe uploaded
$remote_file = "";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    exit;
    }
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

and

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Example from that page:

```
<?php
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/');
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY );
?>
```

and

```
<?PHP
        $destination_path = "src/bin/";

//where you want to throw the file on the webserver (relative to your login dir)

    $destination_file = $destination_path."img.jpg";

//This will create a full path with the file on the end for you to  use, I like splitting the variables like this in case I need to use on on their own or if I'm dynamically creating new folders.

        $file = $myFile['tmp_name'];

//Converts the array into a new string containing the path name on the server where your file is.

    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);// upload the file
    if (!$upload) {// check upload status
        echo "FTP upload of $destination_file has failed!";
    } else {
        echo "Uploaded $file to $conn_id as $destination_file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! How, though, can I get the full file path of the file that needs to be uploaded to the server by using the input type='browse' ?

Comment: No, you will need to set your own path in the code. @turkey3

Comment: @turkey3 Having any success yet?

Comment: So wait, a full directory is needed for both server-side file and client-size file?